# How to set custom dir to generate certs in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Using kubeadm we can use *--cert-dir* to use the custom dir to save and store the certificates.

`--cert-dir The path where to save and store the certificates. (default "/etc/kubernetes/pki")`

How can we set the custom dir in minikube?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/) is the main bootstrapper for `minikube` implementation by default, thus it can be possible to pass to `minikube` special `kubeadm` command line [parameters](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/configuring_kubernetes.md#kubeadm) via `--extra-config` flag.

The target configuration with desired effect to change certificates inventory directory via `--cert-dir` flag may looks like:

```
$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none --extra-config=kubeadm.cert-dir="/$CERTS_PATH"
```

However , since I've launched the above code, I've received the following error:

> minikube v1.2.0 on linux (amd64)
>
> Sorry, the kubeadm.cert-dir parameter is currently not supported
>   by --extra-config

From `minikube` help guide:

> Valid kubeadm parameters: ignore-preflight-errors, dry-run,
>   kubeconfig, kubeconfig-dir, node-name, cri-socket,
>   experimental-upload-certs, certificate-key, rootfs, pod-network-cidr

Which actually breaks my plans to get on hand solution as apparently I didn't find any other methods to afford it.

Will go further and share my progress though...